# Change Arr file then include it in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got some `arr` file that I need to change. It is https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android library and I need to change something in xml file (values directory) to make it work and include it in my project in Android Studio. This is what I did ( I tryed other ways too but without success):

1. Changed arr extension to zip
2. extracted it with WinRAR
3. made changes to xml
4. Packaged it again and changed to arr extension again
5. In android studio I went `File->New->New module->Import JAR/ARR Package.`
6. If it is not added automatically I would add `compile(:LibBlinkId)` to gradle

Unfortunatelly when I start typing com.microblink... I don't get intellisense, meaning that library was not added. Also I tryed to rename it to .jar file, then added it to libs directory and go to : File->Project Structure-> selected my app module and added that jar, then in gradle I put something like   `compile files('libs/LibBlinkID.jar')`

That did not help also.

Comment: Why downwvote ?

Answer (score 1):

After changing your `build.gradle` you should also do a `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

If there were no errors during this step, I see no reason why your method wouldn't work except for the fact that on step 6 it should be:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':LibBlinkId')
    ...

}
```

If Android studio somehow failed to sync up to your dependencies you might want to try an `Invalidate Caches / Restart` from the `File` menu and follow that with a project rebuild.

#### Update:

If that still does not work but the project builds successfully, try to manually import a known class from the `AAR` and to use that class in a small piece of code. Then run your app.

When dependency import failures happened to me, after such a manual step `Android Studio` autocomplete would start to work and give me the correct suggestions.